# no puedo resolver IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: unity, unity2d

me salio este error "IndexOutOfRangeException" y no se como resolverlo

este es mi codigo:

```html
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowTrap : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float attackCooldown;
    [SerializeField] private Transform firePoint;
   [SerializeField] private GameObject[] arrows;
    private float cooldownTimer;
    
    private void Attack()
    {
        cooldownTimer = 0;

        arrows[0].transform.position = firePoint.position;
        arrows[0].GetComponent<EnemyProjectile>().ActivateProjectile();
    }
    
    private int FindArrow()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrows.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!arrows[i].activeInHierarchy)
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        cooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (cooldownTimer >= attackCooldown)
            Attack();
    }
}
```

y aunque si le agregue un objeto a arrows, me sale el error

si me pueden explicar porque sale el error y darme una solucion se los agradeceria

Agrego un elemento a arrows desde unity, como se puede ver en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En qué momento agregas algo a “arrows”? Por lo que veo, al momento de que attack se ejecuta, el arreglo arrows no tiene ningún objeto y por lo tanto el índice 0 excede los índices válidos del arreglo, ya que está vacío.

Comment: Saludos. En relación al código que compartes y tu comentario; te sugiero colocar un breakpoint o salida a consola (o alguna forma de "observar") antes de solicitar elemento del array. Básicamente cuando quieres/refieres un elemento ese no existe. Es como si tuvieras 2 elementos y pides el tercero.